# Re-enable warning when attempting to debug release build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When Starting/Debugging code, there is a warning dialog notifying you that you are currently on a release build and the code won't debug/breakpoint/etc. correctly.

I've just accidentally selected the fourth "Always debug anyway (Don't ask again)" option, but I'd like to continue to be warned about this.

Where can I reset this setting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Goto Tools -> Options.

Check the option for "Warn if no user code on launch"

[image: Sreenshot]

<sup>*click to enlarge the picture*</sup>

Comment: This helped me a lot, but I also had to restart VS, for the warning to start showing up again.

Comment: In VS 2022 I was able to get the message back w/o restart VS