# Visual Studio: Get message "You are debugging a Release build ..." back - after click "Don't ask me again"

Tags: visual-studio

I started a debugger session on a Release configuration.
Visual Studio kindly asked me, are you sure ... "You are debugging a Relase build ... so may your breakpoints will not be hit" - see screenshot.

Thanks to ["You are debugging a release build" when debug is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56449866/10655742) - I was able to "steal" the screenshot of the message.

[image: Message "you are debugging a Relase build ...]

I clicked by accident on "Continue debugging (Don't Ask Again)" :-(

My question is how can I get the message back, so revoke my "Don't ask again".

I checked the settings of Visual Studio, but I don't see / find the relevant settings entry. Has anyone an idea? many thanks.

[image: Visual Studio - settings - Debug]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

[SO - Re-enable warning when attempting to debug release build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48766081/10655742)

Goto Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Check "Warn if no user code on launch (Managed only)" below "Enable Just My Code"